# How to protect all the sheets in a workbook leaving a range of cells opened

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to protect all the sheets in my workbook leaving all a certain range of cells opened.
The first action is to unprotect the range and then moving to the next one

I have tried this approach but it locks only one sheet then bring an error

```
Sub ProtectSheets()
Dim wsheet As Worksheet
For Each wsheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
      Range("I20", "I129").Locked = False
      wsheet.Protect Password:=" "
      MsgBox wsheet.Name
Next wsheet
End Sub
```

Here is the error

Run-time error '1004'
Your changes cannot be made because this is a protected sheet

And when I tried running first the unlocked range code and then the lock sheets in different module. It was only working for the first sheet and all the remaining ones were blocked. I also tried to record a macro but it did not help

I am new to this please help me out

Comment: Fully qualify your range. That’s your problem … wsheet.Range()

Comment: Please sir/madam, can you be more specific and explicit

Comment: wsheet.Range("I20", "I129").Locked = False